# How to unit test the Private Actions in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, nunit

Can we unit test the action which are having access specifier as private? If possible how can we unit test the private actions?

Answer (score 0):

You can but why do you have private action methods? I'd rethink that architecture a little bit more. If you forget to make it private it becomes URL addressable.

However if you really want to do this right click on the method and add a unit test. The unit test project will add an item to the apps assemblyinfo.cs [InternalsVisibleTo] so it's private methods can be accessed via a proxy that's created in the test project.
It's a bit messy may as well pull that out into a separate class and make it public or internal etc

Comment: Can you please give me the example to unit test the private action method in mvc application?

Comment: right click on it, select 'create unit tests' the rest will be done for you.

Answer (score 0):

One option is make the action public and decorate it with `NonActionAttribute`.

Comment: that should never be an option its a bad practice and unfortunate that attribute even exists. If you have a non-routable public method on your controller you are violating what that controller is supposed to do. Put it in another project/class and test that (as mentioned below)  note comments at the end of http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/04/09/asp-net-mvc-using-nonactionattribute-to-restrict-access-to-public-methods-of-controller.aspx